# Turn off Logging @ Here Maps SDK

Tags: swift, logging, heremaps, heremaps-ios-sdk

We have been trying to discover the way to turn off logging in here SDK

We remove the log appender initialisation and setLogAppender call but it does not helped.

`nativeEngine.setLogAppender(appender: AhoyLogAppender())`

Tried setting the scheme to OS_Activity_mode = disable but it also failed.

It will be great if team can share support over the issue.

[Doc Reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-sdk-navigate/4.12.1.0/api_reference/Protocols/LogAppender.html#%2Fs:7heresdk11LogAppenderP3log5level7messageyAA0B5LevelO_SStF)